# Disable "access denied" icon when dragging files to a textbox for Add_DragEnter event

Tags: powershell

I have a some code that allows me to drag a file in File Explorer to a text box on a form. The code works fine. However, a "no access" icon appears over the text box, even though the file can be dragged there  without a problem. Is there some way to stop the icon from appearing?

For clarification the "no access" icon is a circle with a diagonal bar from upper left to lower right of the circle. (From 10 o'clock to 4 o'clock, for those of you who remember when clocks were round and had hands)

Edit: Added code for clarification.

Text box code:

```
$tbxPath = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$tbxPath.Location = '10,30'
$tbxPath.Size = '370,20'
$tbxPath.AllowDrop = $true
$tbxPath.Add_DragOver({$_.Effect = [System.Windows.Forms.DragDropEffects]::Copy})
$tbxPath.Add_DragEnter({ GetFirstFile($_)})
```

Code related to get the file path (not sure if it has any connection to the issue, but I'll include it anyway. For what it is worth, I can use either Add_DragOver or Add_DragEnter to call my GetFirstFile function.)

```
function GetFirstFile($Object){

    $tbxPath.Clear()

    foreach ($File in $Object.Data.GetFileDropList()){

    $tbxPath.Tag = Split-Path $File -Parent

    $tbxPath.Text = Split-Path  $File -Leaf

    $lblInstructions.Text = 'Click the open button'

    $lblInstructions.ForeColor = 'Black'

    $cbOpen.Focus()

    break

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the definition of your textbox:

```
$textBox.AllowDrop = $true
$textBox.Add_DragOver({$_.Effect = [System.Windows.Forms.DragDropEffects]::Copy})
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Theo, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't work so I'll add my code to my original comment so you can see what I'm attempting.

Comment: Actually, I can see the cursor change to a copy icon once it is over the textbox. But the problem seems to be it changes to the no access icon as soon as the cursor is over the form itself.

Comment: @Andrew I went by the title of your question _"dragging files to a textbox"_, but if you want the whole form to behave like that, simply change the two lines into `$form.AllowDrop = $true; 
$form.Add_DragOver({$_.Effect = [System.Windows.Forms.DragDropEffects]::Copy})`

Comment: Theo, that works! I tried adding ```{$_.Effect = [System.Windows.Forms.DragDropEffects]::Copy}``` to the textbox ```Add_DragOver``` code yesterday, but it didn't work. Wasn't aware that form worked in the same way, so thanks for not just the code, but also increasing my knowlege of forms overall.